# Non-proprietary Presentation / Vector Graphics Animation

Tags: presentation, vector-graphics, animation, powerpoint

I would like a WYSIWYG editor similar to Power Point (or Hyper Card) but the output needs to be readable in a standard way that can be easily embedded in another app without licencing issues. We'd also like to avoid pressing issues of abandonment / security flaws (Flash etc.).  One option is to convert power-point to html 5. An Adobe tool is claimed to have this feature as well as an [online converter](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/) which I have not tried.  There are also projects such as reveal.js which may allow editing in a more html5 friendly format. I expect to have large and complicated presentations. I might appreciate some suggestions from someone who has used one of these options or another option for vector graphics presentations to help me weigh my options.

Answer (score 1):

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) has the following features:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform (Windows, OS-X & Linux)
- Just about all of the power of PowerPoint
- Export as html with a choice of image formats, (each slide will be an image).
- Full GUI for designing your slideshows
- Presenter mode, *(i.e. Slides on one screen with timer, notes & preview on another)*
- Part of an integrated suite and can use data from the rest of the suite.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work because LibreOffice may not be lightweight enough to bundle and I am not sure how easy it will be to embed the player. Also, many slides are choreographed sequences of fade-ins and fade-outs, so reducing each slide to a static image is not acceptable.